# How can I get SMTP server response using JavaMail?

Tags: java, smtp, response, jakarta-mail

I'm using JavaMail 1.5 to send mail and see from my tests that messages are sent successfully.
I use `SMTPTransport` to get last server response, but it's empty, same as code. `getReportSuccess()` returns `false`.

```
SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtps");
t.send(message);
String response = t.getLastServerResponse();
boolean s = t.getReportSuccess();
int code = t.getLastReturnCode();
return response;
```

What can be the reason of getting such response, though the message is sent successfully?

Is there any way to get correct SMTP response?

Comment: Hi, I actually found the reason, it seems to be important to connect if you use SMTPTransport.
Though you still can send e-mails using send() method - response will be empty.
The issue is fixed with such code:

    SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtp");
                t.connect();
                t.sendMessage(message,message.getAllRecipients());
                String response = t.getLastServerResponse();
                boolean s = t.getReportSuccess();
                int code = t.getLastReturnCode();
                return response;

Comment: Exactly.  Transport.send creates its own Transport instance to use, and you have no direct access to it.  Creating your own Transport instance and using the sendMessage method is the way to go.

Comment: hello , you should have answered your own question , instead of this comment you have made . can you make time for it ?

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure that it is completely cover this question, but as I glanced on [SMTPTransport.java](https://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/source/browse/mail/src/java/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPTransport.java?r=3), the description to `getReportSuccess()` says:

```
/**
     * Should we report even successful sends by throwing an exception?
     * If so, a <code>SendFailedException</code> will always be thrown and
     * an {@link com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressSucceededException
     * SMTPAddressSucceededException} will be included in the exception
     * chain for each successful address, along with the usual
     * {@link com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException
     * SMTPAddressFailedException} for each unsuccessful address.
     *
     * @return  true if an exception will be thrown on successful sends.
     *
     * @since JavaMail 1.3.2
     */
    public synchronized boolean getReportSuccess() {
        return reportSuccess;
    }
```

So, in my code, to be made sure that sending proccess has been successfuly done, I invoked `setReportSuccess(true);` before sending and then handled an exception `com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressSucceededException`. The following code snippet works for me fine:

```
public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String user, String oauthToken, String recipients, String attachment)
{
    try {
        SMTPTransport smtpTransport = connectToSmtp("smtp.gmail.com", 587, user, oauthToken, true);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        /*Set whether successful sends should be reported by throwing
        **an exception.
        */
        smtpTransport.setReportSuccess(true);

        /**
        ***All actions to got the formated message
        **/

        /*Send message*/
        smtpTransport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    } catch(android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException e){
        Log.d("MY_LOG","NetworkOnMainThreadException");
    }
    catch(com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressSucceededException e){
        /**
        ***Message has been sent. Do what you need.
        **/         
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("MY_LOG", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```